# Foreach loop returns all results

Tags: laravel, loops

I have a column of album covers. I want to take me to the album details after click on the cover. Actually it takes me to the album details but it shows all results, not only this one which was clicked.

AlbumDetailsController

```
public function index(): View
{
    return View("details.index", [
        'albums' => Album::paginate(1)
]);
}
```

AlbumDetails Blade view

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        @foreach ($albums as $album)
        <h1 class="my-4"><a href="#" class="text-dark">{{ $album->name }}</a></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                        </h4>
                        <a href="#" class="text-dark">{{ $album->artist }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="{{asset('storage/' . $album->image_path)}}" alt="" class="img-fluid card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">
                            <a href="#" class="text-dark">{{ $album->artist }}</a>
                        </h4>
                        <a href="#" class="text-dark">{{ $album->description }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

I've tried to solve this in differents ways but everything is not working. I think problem is with my controller but I'm really don't know how to modify it to show only this item which was clicked.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the only code you are showing would have a Collection with 1 item in it so not sure what part of this would have more than 1 item to iterate

Comment: where is your show method?     return View("details.show", [
        'albums' => Album::findOrFail($album->id)
]);